# Cannot understand recursion in this python program using turtle

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle

def tree(branchLen,t):
    if branchLen > 5:
        t.forward(branchLen)
        t.right(40)
        tree(branchLen-15,t)
        t.left(80) #I don't get what happens after this.
        tree(branchLen-15,t)
        t.right(40)
        t.backward(branchLen)

def main():
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    myWin = turtle.Screen()
    t.left(90)
    t.up()
    t.backward(100)
    t.down()
    t.color("green")
    tree(75,t)
    myWin.exitonclick()

main()
```

I cannot understand recursion in this python program. I get that it takes branchLen and if it is greater than 5, it draws forward(branchLen) then changes angle by 40degrees right. Then function is called again with branchLen reduced by 15 and again till branchLen is less than 5.

Then it turns the turtle left by 40 degrees  and calls the function again **But this time when it reduces branchLen by 15 shouldn't it now be negative?** So now function shouldn't work as its if condition is that branchLen > 5.?

Comment: every recursive algorithm has a base case.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think that `branchLen` gets reduced when it really isn't. Calling `tree(branchLen-15,t)` only reduces `branchLen` for the recursive call, not in the current call. It's not like `branchLen -= 15`. So:

- `main` calls `tree(75,t)`.
- `tree(75,t)` calls `tree(60,t)` and then `tree(60,t)` again (after rotating). Not `tree(45,t)`.
- Each `tree(60,t)` calls `tree(45,t)` twice (so `tree(45,t)` gets called four times overall).
- ...
- Each `tree(15,t)` calls `tree(0,t)` twice.
- Each `tree(0,t)` does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> But this time when it reduces branchLen by 15 shouldn't it now be negative? So now function shouldn't work as its if condition is that branchLen > 5.?

That's exactly what happens. When `branchLen` is smaller than 5 the recursion stops. Otherwise you would have endless recursion calls.